# I want to hear the ping

Tags: linux, ping

I want to hear the audible ping

Load module

```
modprobe pcspkr
```

Xset

```
xset b
```

And now ping...

```
ping -a myhost
```

But I hear nothing!
Why?
I'm on real pc,slackware 14.2 on Asus usb3/M3
terminal is xfce4-terminal,with xterm works

Comment: Physical machine or VM guest? Which distribution? What hardware (make/model of computer)? What terminal client (actual screen, `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently [the bell is not enabled by the default](http://www.bio.brandeis.edu/~shaikh/linux/beep.htm) in `xfce4-terminal`. The fix is

1. Go to `.config/Terminal`
2. Open `terminalrc` in a text editor.
3. Find the `MiscBell` setting, and change it to `TRUE`.

Comment: I like this solution,so it win

Answer (score 3):

To make a machine beep when it is pinged:

Install `sox` and setup sudo such that `sudo tcpdump` requires no password.

On the machine you wish to make sound:

```
while true; do sudo tcpdump -v -nn -i eno1 -c 1 icmp; play -n synth 0.1 sin 880; done
```

Replace `play -n synth 0.1 sin 880` with `echo -e "\a"` if you prefer console beeping. You might have to pipe it to a /dev/tty file if you are using ssh.

Replace `eno1` with your network interface.

Then ping the machine with `ping -c1` and hear the beep.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found.
On xterm work
on xfce4-terminal not
So is probably a bug or a misconfiguration of xfce4 terminal

Comment: Is there a setting in `xfce4-terminal` (like there is in `xterm`, `putty` and maybe others) to toggle the bell between visual and audible notification?

Comment: As I know not,but if someone know maybe help

Answer (score 1):

For other people's sake who are finding this:

It's possible that you don't have a physical PC speaker or the cable for it is not plugged in to the motherboard. It's not uncommon for modern PCs to be missing them or have them disabled in the BIOS. One way you might be able to tell if you have one is if your computer beeps when it boots up.  Not beeping doesn't mean that you don't have one though.